# StreamBuilder's snapshot is not giving all data emitted by Stream in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

I am trying the below code to print 1, 2 and 3 on a `Text` widget. But the problem is its only printing 1 and 3. But by property concat should print all data sequentially right?

```
Stream<String> get concatStream => Observable.concat(
      [new Observable.just(1.toString()),
      new Observable.timer(2.toString(), new Duration(seconds: 1)),
      new Observable.just(3.toString())]);
```

The weird part is, if I use the below configuration. It's printing all the 3 values sequentially. What can be the problem?

```
Stream<String> get concatStream => Observable.concat([
        new Observable.just(1.toString()),
        new Observable.timer(2.toString(), new Duration(seconds: 2)),
        new Observable.timer(3.toString(),new Duration(seconds: 1))
      ]);
```

Code of my `StreamBuilder`:

```
return StreamBuilder(
        stream: getStream(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            return Text(
              snapshot.data,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error");
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
```

Comment: read [StreamBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) documentation: *"
The builder is called at the discretion of the Flutter pipeline, and will thus receive a timing-dependent sub-sequence of the snapshots that represent the interaction with the stream.

As an example, when interacting with a stream producing the integers 0 through 9, the builder may be called with any ordered sub-sequence of the following snapshots that includes the last one (the one with ConnectionState.done):"*

Comment: Yeah now I got it. But don't you think its not a good approach to miss out some data. I was just scratching my head from past 2 hours over this funny behaviour. Btw thanks for that comment. But any idea how to resolve this if I want all the 3 values? @pskink

Comment: simply `Listen()` that `Stream`

Comment: maybe there is another way in [async](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async) package? or use `Stream#transform` which simply returns the same element?

Comment: Actually the `Listen()` method as mentioned by you didn't work. I was checking with the 2nd configuration which was already working.

Comment: what does not work in `listen()`? it skips the data? how come?

Comment: Yeah got it working. It was just wrong method I calling. Thanks again.